# Is Taqleed Fard in Islam?

Tags: madhhab, fard, taqlid

Many of the followers of the 4 schools of thought claim that it is Fard to do Taqleed and join one of the 4 schools while there are others like Salafis who claim that Taqleed by a non-layman can be a form of Shirk and is Haram.

The definition of Taqleed is very important for this question:

*Taqleed:*

> To follow the statements of an individual whose statement is not from
>   the four proofs (Hujjah) of the Shareeah and the statement is without
>   evidence (Daleel).

This definition of Taqleed is approved and accepted by the contemporary Deobandis, as Taqi Usmani says, Taqleed is to follow the opinions of a person, whose opinion is not a proof in Islamic law without asking for his proof (i.e. the Muqallid does not ask the proof from the person whose opinion he follows).

Quoted from, "The Legal status of following a Madhhab" by Moulana Muhammad Taqi Usmani. The definition is attributed to Ibn Hummam and Ibn Nujaim.

So, is Taqleed of one of the four schools Fard in this age of Information?

Comment: It sounds like you answered the question already - you quoted the Deobandi as well as the Salafi position. It's unlikely that the "correct" answer will be hashed out here.

Comment: I just clarified what I knew and the research component of the question.I did not give proofs for either